USDT contract dont have ERC20permit
I want to allow user who is the holder of usdt to allow relayer to spend token on his behalf to save gas fee. USDT dont have permit as far as i searched. I dont want to use approve because it cost gas if i'm saving user from gas fee then it is not making sense to approve relayer to pay gas and then relayer transfer. I want to know how can i achieve permit kind of thing.
I'm using USDT polygon contract
Thanks in advance

Unfortunately, unless Tether adds this feature via smart contract upgrade, it's not possible.

Thanks for your response. The third parties that are talking about meta transactions they also use permit / approve  right? So if contract dont have permit functionality then gasless transaction can never be achieved right? I'm just asking to confirm what third parties do and are they also unable to help this usecase?

It can be done with ERC-4337 chain level account abstraction. But this needs rewriting all wallet software, etc. Not sure if anyone is doing it yet in large scale.

Thanks again I think ERC-4337 is in draft stage and not finalized and accepted as a standard till now or any thing i missed? and can i please get the final words So that i can close this thread can u please acknowledge if its in draft then there is no way to do gasless tranfer without using permit functionaliy because already deployed contract dont have permit. So, If i want to achieve gasless transfer then i need to create my own usdt contract am i right about this? Thanks

Yes if we specifically speak about Polygon, Polygon mainnet cannot do that. Not sure if ever will.

Thanks alot brother
